# how to add button controls in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am showing records in tableview. My each row is displaying title of record, one profile image, username. It all is showing perfectly. But now I have to add one button with image ("like" image in facebook). Whenever user will click on that partcular "like" button an event should occur. And whenever user will click on title of row new nib file will be loaded.

1) How will I add image which should have an event occur method defined.
2) How will I distinguish where clicked event occurred ( title OR "like" image).

Here are part of code which is adding value in table and adding profile images in each row.

```
// Code which is adding image of facebook and Twitter in each row as per data


if([[imageData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]isEqualToString:@"facebook"])
{

    UIImage *leftImage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"facebook.png"];
    cell.imageView.image= leftImage;

}
else if([[imageData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]isEqualToString:@"twitter"]){
    UIImage *leftImage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"twitter_bird_normal.jpg"];
    cell.imageView.image= leftImage;
}
```

and here is code which is adding values in table

```
...
...
[tableList addObject:facebookValue]; //facebookValue is string parsing from JSON
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIButton with type: UIButtonTypeCustom
Set it's image to your leftImage.
Add a target and selector to the button that points to a delegate and a method.  This is the event you're looking for.
Also, tag the button with the indexPath.row so you know which row it came from.
Add the button as a subview to the cell.