# How to add image and buttons in UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have to add one image, one label and one button in each cell. How will I add these 3 different controls in a UITableview?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    cell.imageView.image = <you image>;
    cell.textLabel.text = <your text>;
  }
```

Both of the previous answers do not handle this correctly as they

1. Do not actually create/get a cell
2. Add subview directly to cell when you should normally add to the content view `cell.contentView`

I did try to edit the original answer but no one has accepted it

Comment: i am getting result but not perfectly. All buttons are coming a bit below not showing in each cell. and also when I am dragging vertical it is becoming disappear and appear. And also method "aMethod" is not calling. when I am clicking on button it is being clicked on cell.

Comment: Now that I have thought about this question some more I am unsure why you are adding a button to each cell? You will have to create a workaround to determine what cell the button was actually on so you can associate the method being called to any specific cell. Maybe a little more context can lead to a better answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634632/how-to-add-button-controls-in-tableview-in-iphone  . Here you will get what I am doing and what I want to do. Please go there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [cell addSubview:button];
    }
```

//Like this you can add the Label and the image

Comment: It will add one button, how will I add one smiley image ("smiley.png" and any hardcode text "like" just beside of button? thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normallook.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; 


[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[cell addSubview:button];
 }
```

Comment: Above is adding one button in cell. I have to add three controls 1) image 2) Text label 3) button with image (which is above code). Here it is adding one buuton with image but how will I add next 2 controls. All three controls are beside of each other. I mean one cell will keep three controls.

Comment: how did we add the above button like so create other 2 then add to cell with different frame value.